# How csrf token is handled on 443 and 444 ports

Tags: nginx, networking, https, csrf-token

The nginx conf is managed in two parts: 443 port and 444 port.

The route is different, but they're all the same
443 is connected normally and 444 is experiencing 403 error.

ex)
443 -> web1 (access)
444 -> web2 (403 error, csrf verification error)

If you connect to each conf by changing the port number,
it runs the other way around

444 -> web1 (403 error, csrf verification error)
443 -> web2 (access)

as a solution
444 port conf with proxy_set_headerhost value
$host; -> $http_host;
As I changed it, 444 ports work well too.

My question is this.
Is port 443 a standard port for HTTPS,
so does it deliver the csrf token value well?

I wonder how csrf token is handled on 443 and 444 ports.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
    location /
        ...
        root /usr/share/nginx/web1;
        index index.html index.htm;
        ...
    }
```

```
server {
    listen 444 ssl;
    ...
    location /
        ...
        root /usr/share/nginx/web2;
        index index.html index.htm;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the csrf token verify  has any relation to nginx listen port. Check the csfr token in you request both from the clinet and the server side.

Comment: thanks comment,
It is confirmed that the request includes the csrf token issued by the server.

Comment: But it should not by the port. The content in your question may have nothing to do with this issue. You may have to check other thing.

Comment: I can guess one situation is that, you hybrid the two port in your site, which may cause the cors issue. For cors is will be influenced by the port.